# helm: delete releases in a sequence

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an umbrella chart that i am installing on a kubernetes env. It contains 2 components. Component2 is installed after Component1 and this works fine.

```
helm install --debug --name <release-name> .
```

I am having issues with the `helm delete --purge <release-name>` this release. I need to ensure that component2 is deleted before component1 else the pods of component2 go into CrashLoopBackOff state looking for the service of component1.

I tried writing a pre-delete hook to set weights. I am not sure if this is the right approach, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above issue was resolved by adding '.spec.podManagementPolicy' in the stateful set. To resolve the issue that I faced, set the podManagementPolicy to 'Parallel'

[Reference][1]: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#pod-management-policy